# Vaadin - Trigger button click within table

Tags: java, vaadin

**In [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home), is it possible to simulate the click of a button which is located within a [Table](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html)?**

e.g:

```
table.getCellContent(tableRowId, columnRowId).clickButton()
```

The reason that I'm asking is since I need this for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in Vaadin 6.8.0 and later versions:

```
((Button) table.getContainerProperty(tableRowId, columnRowId).getValue()).click();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Right now I'm currently trying to fetch the columnId, but it seems that the generated button column cells that I'm looking for aren't present (the other generated columns are however present). :(

Comment: In the case of generated columns, you have to save a reference to the generated components to a Map and access the buttons from there.

Comment: Ah, really? Because I can see other generated columns (for text) present. So when you have other generated components in a table you basically have to keep a reference to all of them outside of the table as well then?